# How to make python not close it self after error, python exception

Tags: python, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I have made an program in python that i converted into .exe using auto-py-to-exe and im wondering how to stop .exe stop closing it self after an error (python exception) the .exe closes it self in the speed of light and you cant read the error.

Does someone knows how to make it not close it self?

using input doesnt work if the exception happens in a pip library

Thanks

Comment: Use a [try except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except block print the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what the question has to do with auto-py-to-exe. Why wouldn't the problem be the same with an ordinary Python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except based system (that you have to build suitably to catch every exception of your code) and to print the exception you can use the module traceback like so:

```
try:
    ## code with error ##
except Exception:
    print("Exception in user code:")
    print("-"*60)
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    print("-"*60)
```

or you could use a simpler form like:

```
try:
    ## code with error ##
except Exception as e:
    print(e, file='crash log.txt')
```

that only prints the error class (like file not found).

I should also point out that the `finally` keyword exists with the purpose of executing code either if an exception arose or not:

```
try:
    ## code with error ##
except:                                             #optional
    ## code to execute in case of exception ##
finally:
    ## code executed either way ##
```

Something you could do on top of that is logging everything your program does with

`print(status_of_program, file=open('log.txt','a'))`

this is useful to see exactly at what point the program has crashed and in general to see the program in action step by step.

But a thing you should do is properly test the program while in .py form and if it works you could possibly assume the error comes from the actual exportation method and consult the documentation or try exporting simpler programs to catch the difference (and so the error).

i'd suggest to consult:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html
to learn the error types and the try-except construct.

---

If input() doesn't work try using `sys.stdout()`.

Comment: Don't forget `else:` for code to run after the try block, if an exception did not occur, and before the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that this is a console app. If it's a GUI app, you can use a similar approach but the details will be different.

The approach I'd use is to set `sys.excepthook` to be your own function that prints the exception, then waits for input. You can call the existing exception hook to actually do the printing.

```
import sys, traceback as tb

oldhook = sys.excepthook

def waitexcepthook(type, exception, traceback):
    oldhook(type, exception, traceback)
    input()

sys.excepthook = waitexcepthook
```